# php creating a repeating form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, variables, argument-passing

I am trying to create a repeating form that passes variable and  updates the table each time the page is submitted.

for example:

```
<form action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method="post">
<p>Student Name: <input type="text" name='studentName[]' size='32'></p>


<button type="submit" name='submit' value='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>


<?php  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$studentName[]=$_POST['studentName']; 

?>
<table border='1'>
<tr><th>Students Name</th></tr>


<?php 
for($x=0; $x < count($studentName); $x++)
{
echo "<tr><td>$studentName[$x]</td></tr>";  
} ?>
</table>


}

   ?>
```

I know that the above code does not work. What would be the correct way to do something like this? Can someone please write me a correct code that does work. I need to see an example.

I searched all over the internet, but I could not find an example.

Comment: Which part of it doesn't work? The form submission (because you have `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but you're not outputting it via PHP like `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`)? Does it not create the rows? Does it look bad? etc...

Comment: Why are you using an array for `name` when you have just a single input box?

Comment: if you need data to be saved after page submit, you should use some permament data storage. For example database.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare $studentName[] as array befor $studentName = array()